# Unable to swipe across on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, ruby, cucumber, appium

I am having issues trying to use the swipe functionality on the ios app. Currently using Appium v1.3.5 in conjuction with Cucumber/RubyMine v7.04.

I have tried using a range of x, y co-ordinates. However I am still only able to swipe half way and unable to click on the element on screen.

Has anyone come across this issue before?

```
def self.hide_thread
action = Appium::TouchAction.new
action.press(x: 360, y: 70).move_to(x: 0, y: 70).release
sleep(1)
find_element(:xpath,"//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATableView[1]/UIATableCell[1]/UIAButton[1]").click
end
```

Please error message:

```
elementId 18 could not be tapped(Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
  ./features/step_definitions/hidden_threads.rb:82:in `hide_thread'
  ./features/step_definitions/hidden_threads.rb:102:in `/^Hide the thread$/'
  features/hidden_threads.feature:8:in `And Hide the thread'
Then Thread will be hidden       # features/step_definitions/hidden_threads.rb:105
```

Answer (score 0):

for java I found this solution! you try for ruby to pass deltax and deltay instead of end point coordinates and update this answer if needed.
[Check This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38582089/1802348)

1. swipe(100,200,10,20,300) => swipe starting from Point (100,200) and end at Point (110,220) which means finger would move Right lower side fro current position
2. swipe(100,200,-10,20,300) => swipe starting from Point (100,200) and end at Point (90,220) which means finger would move Left lower side from current position
3. swipe(100,200,10,-20,300)=> swipe starting from Point (100,200) and end at Point (110,180) which means finger would move Right Upper side from current position
4. swipe(100,200,-10,-20,300)=> swipe starting from Point (100,200) and end at Point (90,180) which means finger would move Left Upper side from current position